# Google Calendar API batch inserting has stopped working

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have an application that has been successfully using HTTP batch requests to insert, edit, and delete events via the Google Calendar API. In the last couple of days, the individual requests within the batches have started returning 404 errors (although the batch itself gets a 200 success response). Making those same requests as individual requests using the same authorization header is still working.

I'm pretty sure that this isn't related to the [forthcoming shutdown of Google's global HTTP batch endpoints](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/discontinuing-support-for-json-rpc-and.html) because we're using https://www.googleapis.com/batch/calendar/v3 as our endpoint.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/batch/calendar/v3
Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_google_calendar

--batch_google_calendar
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <item-0-batchevent@example.com>

POST calendar/v3/calendars/your_calendar_id@group.calendar.google.com/events
Content-Type: application/json

{"summary":"batch API test","start":{"date":"2020-07-31"},"end":{"date":"2020-07-31"}}
--batch_google_calendar--
```

And the response is:

```
--batch_3J6sfuPtVQbjZLcpUe06245gKlO31YnC
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <response-item-0-batchevent@example.com>

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Vary: Origin
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Referer
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

[{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "URL path: /v3/calendars/your_calendar_id@group.calendar.google.com/events could not be resolved. Maybe there is an error parsing the batch item.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
]
--batch_3J6sfuPtVQbjZLcpUe06245gKlO31YnC--
```

And here's an example of an individual request that's working:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/your_calendar_id@group.calendar.google.com/events
Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token
Content-Type: application/json

{"summary":"API test","start":{"date":"2020-07-31"},"end":{"date":"2020-07-31"}}
```

Why might the individual request be succeeding but the batch request fail?

Comment: Just to doublecheck: when you perform the tach request and the individual request - do you authenticate with the same account? Because your error message indicates that you authenticate with an account that does not have access to the calendar (or that you misspelled the calendar url).

Comment: @ziganotschka Thanks for the reply! The batch request and individual request are using the same Authorization header. The individual request in my tests was built by taking the URL (including the calendar ID) from the batch request and posting directly to that, so I'm as sure as I can be that the authorisation header and URL are correct.

Comment: I saw a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/162564914) filed on Issue Tracker. I do not know if it was you or another user affected, but in any case - ltes see what the outcome will be!

Comment: @ziganotschka Yes, I added something to the issue tracker this morning. I'll post on here if I get a useful reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google gave a helpful reply via their issue tracker: there was an error in the way that batch entry paths were specific in my application. This had worked without errors until last week, so I think something must have changed at their end to make it less tolerant of mistakes.

The error we had made was omitting the leading slash in the path in each batch entry. Here's what we were doing:

```
POST calendar/v3/calendars/your_calendar_id@group.calendar.google.com/events
```

And here's what we should have been doing:

```
POST /calendar/v3/calendars/your_calendar_id@group.calendar.google.com/events
```

I hope that this might be helpful to anyone else who ever finds themselves in a similar situation!